# How can we push reposatery from Google Colaboratory to Github

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can able to clone,add and commit files to local repose on Google Colaboratory, but am trying to push it to github it's not working. How can i push it to github

Comment: What command did you run, and what error did you encounter? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
os.chdir(YOUR_DIRECTORY)
!git add *
!git config user.email "YOUR_EMAIL@gmail.com"
!git commit -a -m 'message'
!git push https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME:YOUR_GITHUB_PASSWORD@github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME/YOUR_REPOSITORY_NAME.git --all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more details in this article.

https://medium.com/@oyewusiwuraola/how-to-work-with-github-in-google-colaboratory-notebook-18a414dd91ec

It's similar to the answer above.